# package system broken

Tags: package-management

While attempting updates in 12.04, I'm getting the following error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
linux-generic: Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.45.54 is installed
               Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.45.54 is installed
```

I've read other queries here, and tried various suggested solutions, such as disabling third party repositories, looking for broken packages in Synaptic, trying `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get -f install` etc., without success.

Comment: After trying almost everything in http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies[/link] without success, I finally got around to changing the update server from "Server for United States" to "Main server" and then updating worked without a hitch. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that you try to update your own system while the Ubuntu archive itself is being updated. Such problems fix by themselves after a few hours or a day.

Comment: Thanks @tombert. That may be what was involved, as indicated in my prior comment, which I posted before reading your answer.